# Могут ли следующие константы сделать тип не POD-ом?

Tags: c++, c, struct, pod

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
struct POD
{
    static const uint32_t CONST_1;
    static constexpr uint32_t CONST_2;

    uint32_t Member_1;
    uint8_t Member_2;
};
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, является ли данный тип `POD`-ом?

Я хочу использовать `POD` структуру для общения через границу `DLL`. Но мне также хотелось бы, чтобы в этой структуре находились кое-какие формальные константы, к которым было бы удобно обращаться из кода, например, так:

```
POD::CONST_1
POD::CONST_2
```

Не сломают ли таки константы представление структуры в памяти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статические поля не хранятся внутри экземпляров класса, так что ваша структура останется POD.

> Static members of a class are not associated with the objects of the class: they are independent variables with static or thread (since C++11) storage duration or regular functions. 
>   [Источник](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)

В этом легко убедиться на примере:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test
{
    static uint32_t testVar;
    uint32_t otherVar;
};

int main() 
{
    cout <<sizeof(test)<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/YLn3Sv) выдает четверку, а не восьмерку, как можно было бы ожидать.